# Scheduling of Custom Resouces on multi-node k8s cluster

Tags: kubernetes, scheduling, kubernetes-custom-resources, kubernetes-cluster

I have created a custom resource through CRD and custom controller. This resource is deployed successfully on one node cluster (minikube). However, I want to deploy multiple custom resources on multi-node cluster i.e, creating custom resource in master node and master node schedules it to one of the worker nodes. Does kubernetes provide support to schedule custom resources like pods?

Thank you.

Comment: A custom resource is normally just a unit of configuration data; there's not really anything to "schedule" _per se_.  What behavior are you hoping to see?  How would you know if a given CR object can "fit" on a given node?  What would your controller do with this information?

Comment: The custom resources are handled by custom controller (this controller would deploy some network functions on nodes according to custom resource specs). There are multiple nodes in my cluster and I want to deploy custom resources on every node based on the availability of node.

Comment: I'm pretty sure your controller logic will need to handle that itself.  I think the only thing that's actually scheduled on to nodes are Pods.

Comment: After some research, I got to know two options where we can schedule custom resources. One is to somehow deploy the custom controller on a pod (one idea could be by creating docker image of controller and running it on a pod) and we can schedule them with default scheduler. The other option is to implement our own scheduler. What do you think would be a better and feasible approach to opt for.

Comment: The _controller_ is probably implemented as a Pod already, and there's probably only one of it in the cluster.  You could implement your task as schedulable Pods, but in that case using a DaemonSet might be easier than writing an operator.  Otherwise, I _think_ you need to write your own scheduler, which would mean watching Node objects in the controller loop as well as your custom resource.